# Iteration (?) in typing rule

Tags: types, agda

I'm trying to formalise [Pretnar's language](http://www.eff-lang.org/handlers-tutorial.pdf) of algebraic effects and handlers.

The operation rule (op) has one of the premisses of the following format:

[Γ ⊢ xᵢ : τᵢ] where 1 ≤ i ≤ n

(it's actually more complex than this, you can check for yourself on page 11 of the paper). I have no idea how I can implement this sort of "iteration" on a typing rule. Any pointers? I don't even know how this is usually called.

I assume something like this is possible since I want the language to work for any kind (and number) of operation/effects, and I do not want to have a fixed set of them.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without having more details, but I would try to use a finite set `Fin n` and state the premise of the typing rule as something like `(i : Fin n) -> Γ ⊢ x i : τ i` in Agda.

Comment: what sort of detail?

Comment: A solid description of the typing rule you want to formalize would be a good start.

Comment: The exact rule I want to implement is on page 11 of the paper I linked, it's the fifth rule (the one that takes the full page width). (I suggest the paper cause Pretnar can explain it better that I ever could, and also I don't know what "solid description" entails)